# Error with JNI (Java and C++)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to use `JNI` with `C++` but it is not going right I have justified all the steps to call a `c++` method from `java` . but I am getting following error (Java code and C++ code is given below)

**Java Code is here**

```
public class KeyLogger {
    public native void capture();
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("KeyLogger");
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){

        KeyLogger obj = new KeyLogger();
        obj.capture();
    }
}
```

**C++ code here**

```
**// All libraries included Fucntion goes here.** 

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_KeyLogger_capture
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){

    cout<<"Working Fine"<<endl;
}
void main(){}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: KeyLogger.capture()V
    at KeyLogger.capture(Native Method)
    at KeyLogger.main(KeyLogger.java:10)
```

What should i do for this to get solved

Comment: is your capture method public?

Comment: Have you got your shared library on your `-Djava.library.path`?

Comment: Is your class `KeyLogger` inside of a package?  Is your C++ method declared as `extern "C"`?

Comment: Adam, no its not inside the package and method is not declared extern "C"..

Comment: Elliot , yes shared library is there

Comment: Have you updated VM arguments?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about assistance with spyware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your C++ method as `extern "C"` to ensure that its symbol name is not mangled and can be found by the dynamic linker:

```
extern "C"
{
...
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_KeyLogger_capture(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    ...
}
...
}  // end extern "C"
```

Alternatively, instead of using generated function names which can be difficult to get exactly right, you can use the [`RegisterNatives()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17734) function to register the native methods from within your [`JNI_OnLoad()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_OnLoad) routine.

Comment: Thanks Adam for help. I placed my DLL file **C:\\Windows\\System32\\KeyLogger.dll**
and it worked (it works both with extern and without extern).I dont exactly know what was the issue but it is resolved.